# Mocking $window in angularjs with qunit

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, qunit

I'm pretty new to angular and been wanting to test drive and I've hit a snag mocking out $window.  The item in which I'm attempting to test is very simple but important -- I need to know if localStorage is there or not and need to be able to fake out $window to do so.

The code is very basic so far and what I have is this for the service ...

```
'use strict';

mainApp.factory('somedataStorage',function($window) {
    var local = $window.localStorage;

    return {
        hasLocal: function() {
            return local != undefined;
        },
    };
});
```

How I'm testing it is this ...

```
    (function () {

    var fakeWin = {
        localStorage: null
    };

    var $injector = angular.injector(['ngMock', 'ng', 'mainApp']);
    //var $window = $injector.get('$window');

    var init = {
        setup: function () {
            //this.$window = fakeWin;
        },
    }

    module('LocalStorageTests', init);

    test("if localstorage isn't there, say so", function () {
        var $service = $injector.get('somedataStorage' /*, {$window: fakeWin} */);

        ok(!$service.hasLocal, "no local storage");
    });
})();
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QUnit/Sinon: testing a function which checks if cookies are enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732523/qunit-sinon-testing-a-function-which-checks-if-cookies-are-enabled)